# find files older than x days then output their names and size before deleting them

Tags: linux, find, pipe, exec

I'm trying to find the files that are older than x days then print their names and the total size to a text file before deleting them, the problem is when I combine more than (-exec) option I got errors.
Here is my sh file

```
#!/bin/bash
cache_location=$1
age=$2
date=`date +%d-%m-%Y`
find $cache_location -mtime $2 -path '*keyword*' -fprint deleted_cache_$date.log -exec du -k {} \; | awk '{total+=$1}END{print "TOTAL SIZE " total/1024/1024 "GB"}' >> deleted_cache_$date.log \; 
-exec echo {} | wc -l>> deleted_cache_$date.log \;
-exec rm -r {} \;
```

Then I call the script like:

```
.\myscript.sh location +30
```

The script stops with an error

```
awk: fatal: cannot open file `;' for reading (No such file or directory)
find: ‘du’ terminated by signal 13
```

In the log file, I can see all results of **find** command.

Comment: The pipeline is ending the `find` command, it's not part of the `-exec` option.

Comment: You don't need `-exec echo`, that's what `-print` does.

Comment: But nothing after `| awk` is part of the `find` command.

Comment: Assuming gnu find, `find "$cache_location" -mtime "$2" -path "*keyword*" -fprintf "deleted_cache_$date.log" "%p\t%s\n" -delete`?